Dropdown on vue template not working even if the toggle function is called
I am trying a simple dropdown on a vue project. But the dropdown doesnt drop when I click on it. I have put the console inside the function. The message gets displayed on console that means the function is being called. But it doesnt work.
<template>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button @click="toggleDropdown" class="dropdown-button">
      {{ selectedOption || "Select an option" }}
    </button>
    <ul v-if="isOpen" class="dropdown-menu">
      <li v-for="option in options" :key="option" @click="selectOption(option)">
        {{ option }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  name: "DropDown", // Adding name to the component
  data() {
    return {
      isOpen: false,
      selectedOption: null,
      options: ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleDropdown() {
      console.log("Button clicked");
      this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
    },
    selectOption(option) {
      this.selectedOption = option;
      this.isOpen = false;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-button {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #3498db;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-menu li:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
</style>

When I checked the console, it seems perfectly fine, the click function is called as shows.


I couldn't reproduce this, it worked fine for me.

I added the picture. can you please check it @La Ngoc Hai

Do you mean "drop down" like it having animation? like it doesnt slowly appear or simply doesnt appear at all? Currently I cant find anything wrong with the code, it works well so I need to know what you actually mean. Use dev tool to inspect the  and see if it changes when button is clicked

I tried the code separately in online vue editor too. It works fine there,but same code doesnt work in the project. This is very weird

That's work fine. Could the elements in the dropdown list fall below the other HTML elements?


I tried the code separately in online vue editor too. It works fine there,but same code doesnt work in the project. This is very weird.
